# Spring Boot with Hystrix

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, hystrix

I am using Spring Boot with Hystrix for my university project.
The problem I have is when I add Netflix Hystrix dependency to pom.xml file and run the program, It throws an Error called AbstractMethodError : null, but without Netflix Hystrix dependency program runs without any error. How can I slove this?

These are my dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix-dashboard</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: can you post the stack trace,?

Comment: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null
 at org.springframework.core.OrderComparator.findOrder(OrderComparator.java:142) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationAwareOrderComparator.findOrder(AnnotationAwareOrderComparator.java:65) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.core.OrderComparator.getOrder(OrderComparator.java:125) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.core.OrderComparator.getOrder(OrderComparator.java:113) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
 at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to dependency mismatch. Application is trying to call an abstractt method but it doesn't find that method. So, it is throwing the null exception.

Use two dependency netflix-hystrix-dashboard and hystrix as below.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix-dashboard</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: If you have error even using the two dependency, check the versions of classpath dependency.

Comment: This works for me after change Spring Boot version to 2.1.4